# Ideas to optimize a few subsequent Hibernate load / save calls

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, persistence

I have a simple repository backed up by Hibernate

```
@Repository
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class WidgetDAOImpl implements WidgetDAO {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sf;

    @Override
    public Widget getWidget(long id) {
        return (Widget) sf.getCurrentSession().load(Widget.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveWidget(Widget w){
        sf.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(w);
    }
}
```

This is really simple and is OK. Unfortunately the requirements changed and now I will need to read a lot of and save a lot of widgets - during single business call. Also, the number of business calls will grow.

For instance, this could be the business logic in a separate class:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 100L)                       // lets say this is "often"
public void updateWidgets(List<Long> ids){          // lets say the list is ~10 ids
    for(long id: ids){
        Widget w = widgetDAO.getWidget(id);
        doSomeStuff(w);
        widgetDAO.saveWidget(w);
    }   
}
```

I am affraid this will kill the performance. What can I do to save the performance?

- should I load / save as batches i.e. all at once? I have the list of IDs, so maybe it's possible?
- should I cache the instances somehow other than in session (which is short as you can see)?

Some ideas / **snippets** are really welcome, since I am a Hibernate novice.

Comment: Currently you are creating 2 transactions for each modification. One for the read and one for the write and that for each `Widget` you need. Do everything in a single transactions much better for performance, instead of retrieving each and every single object query for a list and iterate of the items. Save/update in a single batch. If your batches are large save each x items and flush + clear the session after that else your saves will take longer and longer...

Comment: @M.Deinum ok, I will query for lists and save in batches, sure! But how should I merge the transactions into one? Adding `@Transactional` over the business `updateWidgets` is enough? I didnt think about merging so far, since I thought 2 short transactions are better than 1 longer when `updateWidgets` can be called from multiple (~10) threads, with some overlapping IDs..

Comment: @M.Deinum what I mean is that I will have many small transactions, like in the description; say 5 widgets on avg. but very often, every 100ms maybe (dont know yet; assume all the time, on-line..)

Comment: If you have overlapping ids and not a single transaction you will run into different issues (last one wins for isntance depending on your tx settings). A single transaction is also faster as opening a connection to the database, a connection and constructing a hibernate session are long winding tasks (relativly speaking). Just annotating the method with `@Transactional` should do the trick if that doesn't work you could wrap the code in a `TransactionTemplate`.

Comment: @M.Deinum you could make this an aswer, I could accept this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution is creating a lot of transactions. 2 transactions for each item, 1 for the read and 1 for the write.

Creating a transaction is a heavy and time consuming operation (generally) as it will open a connection to the database, start a hibernate session and do some synchronization.

Preferably your whole method is a single transaction and this can be accomplished by annotating your method with `@Transactional`.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 100L)              
@Transactional
public void updateWidgets(List<Long> ids){ ... }
```

When doing this and you have large amounts of data you might want to `flush` and `clear` your current session once in a while.

If you don't want this you should at least make your read and write in a single transaction. For this you can use a `TransactionTemplate` and use this inside your for loop.

```
@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 100L)   
public void updateWidgets(List<Long> ids) {  
    for(long id: ids){
       transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
          protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
              Widget w = widgetDAO.getWidget(id);
               doSomeStuff(w);
               widgetDAO.saveWidget(w);
          }
    }   
}
```

Or move the code in your for loop to a service method which is annotated with `@Transactional`.

Comment: thanks! Just to be sure, the DAO can stay untouched, with its `@Transactional` annotation right?